# making this mysql join code shorter

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, faq and faq_categories, and I want to join them to get the category name from the table faq_categories.

The only field that I need from the faq_categories is the name, while from the faq table, I need all fields.

I have the following syntax (which works) that I would like to make it shorter.

Here is the code:

```
     SELECT faq.faqid, faq.catid, faq.question, faq.question_en, faq.answer,       
        faq.answer_en, faq.sorder, faq.visible, 
        faq_categories.categoryname
FROM faq
JOIN faq_categories ON ( faq.catid = faq_categories.catid )
```

I am trying to select all fields with this code:

```
 SELECT * , faq_categories.categoryname
 FROM faq
 JOIN faq_categories ON ( faq.catid = faq_categories.catid ) 
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But this syntax returns me all fields from both tables which is not what I want. What I want is to get all fields from faq, and only categoryname from faq_categories.

First code snippets works, but I want to make it shorter if that is possible.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, Zoran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `faq.*`.  Simply using `*` will request all columns from all tables.

```
SELECT 
  faq.* ,
  faq_categories.categoryname
FROM faq
  JOIN faq_categories ON ( faq.catid = faq_categories.catid ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Note however, that unless there are quite a lot of columns in `faq`, it is generally recommended to be explicit about which columns you are selecting.  That allows you to specify the order they occur in, and protects you against schema changes that may result in a large number of extra columns being pulled which aren't needed.  Your first instinct to explicitly list columns in your `SELECT` is probably preferable.

Comment: Yes, this do the trick. I will be able to accept your answer in 8 minutes ,due this website limitations. Thanks a lot. I have just 10 fields in faq table, and I need them all. Once again, thanks for your help. - Zoran

Answer (score 1):

use `faq.*, faq_catergories.categoryname`

Comment: yes, works, but I am getting all fields from both tables. what I want is all fields from faq, and only category name from faq_categories

Comment: My answer is no different from Michael's ^^ !! Should have put the full query ;)